# Populate custom list view without custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My question is can we populate the custom listview without creating any custom adapter? I tried to achieve it with the following code where selectedValues is the ArrayList of type String.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    getActivity());
                            ListView listView = (ListView) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.dialogList);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> dialogListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    view.getContext(), R.layout.dialog_list,
                                    selectedValues);
                            listView.setAdapter(dialogListAdapter);
                            builder.setTitle("Selected Informations");
                            builder.setView(listView);
```

Comment: What is your problem now?

Comment: Which problem getting using current code?

Comment: The problem is I am not getting the listview in the dialog but the application collapses

Comment: Are you inflating `view` just for the AlertDialog? Or is it your Fragment's View?

Comment: No I am not inflating the view. it is fragment's view

Comment: That's your problem. The ListView already has a parent View; i.e., it already belongs to the the Fragment's layout. You need to inflate a View just for the AlertDialog. Also, if you just need a basic list of Strings, you might have a look at the `AlertDialog.Builder#setItems()` methods.

Comment: I have tried inflating the view to the AlertDialog. it gives me the view but the list isn't populated

Comment: Is your `selectedValues` null?

Comment: the listview is combination of list and a button

Comment: Do you mean each list item has a Button?

Comment: @jas no it is not null

Comment: @MikeM. yes each row with button and the each selectedValue

Comment: Then you need a custom Adapter, and you'll have to inflate a View just for the AlertDialog. However, if the Button is just meant to select a list item, then it's redundant, and not necessary. Clicking the list item itself can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Ok thanks @MikeM I was looking for alternative methods.